# Using PHP to insert data into a MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to create a self-submitting page that will create a form for a user to fill out. The information will be stored in a MySQL database. The form seems to be working, but I can't insert the information from the form into a database for some reason. Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MySQL Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>MySQL Test</h1>
        <?php

        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
            ?>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
            <?php
        } else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $server = new PDO("mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost", "root", "root");
            $server->execute("INSERT INTO test ('name') VALUES $name;");
        }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

What should I change?

Comment: please, learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY)

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: Try quotes around `$name` in the INSERT statement.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, it's just that no data is appearing in the MySQL database table.

Comment: To get better information about your code, you should wrap it in a try/catch like:
```try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do your insert like this:

```
$name = "john";
$query = "INSERT INTO test(col) VALUES(:name);";
$statement = $server->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(array(":name" => $name));
```

This is called using [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), it's very easy and will avoid sql-injection. You can execute multiple variables on multiple cols on your query by separating with commas after each ":col" => $colVal, but that's not needed here, just a tip.

You can do it for updates aswell.

Remember to check if your being-inserted value is empty or not.

Answer (score 3):

your insert should look as follows:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$server = new PDO("mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost", "root", "root");
$stmt = $server->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (:name)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->execute();
```